# What are the performance advantages of using for(;;) rather than a while() loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

I was looking through a php package and found an interesting line of code which I would like some light shed on.  Rather than passing expressions into the for-loop parameters, all that was written was two semi-colons.

```
for (;;) {  // This is the line in question
  $this->output .= $this->a;
  $this->a       = $this->get();

  if ($this->a === $this->b) {
    break;
  }

  if (ord($this->a) <= self::ORD_LF) {
    throw new JSMinException('Unterminated string literal.');
  }

  if ($this->a === '\\') {
    $this->output .= $this->a;
    $this->a       = $this->get();
  }
}
```

I understand that a for-loop normally contains 3 expressions separated by semi-colons.  So this is clearly just running a for-loop with no expressions and relying on a break (Line 6) to exit the loop.

What I want to know is, **does this method have a performance advantage over the traditional method?**  The way I see it, this could have been easily rewritten as a while loop like so:

```
while($this->a !== $this->b){
  // Loop Contents
}
```

Comment: Your `while()` loop semantically breaks the code, unless you include the two lines above the `if` statement both before the `while()`, and as the last two lines inside the `while()`.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not to the level of coding where I completely understand how to benchmark.  Not to mention, the amount may be so insignificant that it would need many implementations to see a difference.  I was just wondering if anyone had past experience with it, that could yield a quick response.

Comment: @nickb - The `while()` loop would have to be modified to fit the code.  I was just referencing the concept of a while loop instead of a for break loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if it does, and even if it doesn't, I wouldn't sacrifice readability for the slight performance boost. Not unless your app is around Google or Facebook's level of traffic.

Comment: At Google scale, you have much bigger fish to fry.

Comment: This is used in the JSMin package by Ryan Grove, the script is only 300 lines so I would have to think that there are some ulterior motives. But I'm no expert...

Comment: Maybe to save characters? Even if so, I wouldn't do it even if shaved around 20~30% of the loop time.

Comment: @Truth  Sounds fair.  Thank you for your time sir!

Comment: At Google scale you would have a lot bigger pan to fry that fish.
If break of loop depends on some complex condition, then why not...

Answer (score 1):

according to the benchmarks result between for, foreach and while one can conclude that for hase better performance in more cases.take a look at this link.it can be helpfull:

[benchmark](http://www.phpbench.com/)

Answer (score -1):

I think this this is a very bad practice! I will boost your CPU usage to 100% running like this. I think a while is more readable and you should go for that.

Always loop like this, other tasks on that machine get a chance too:

```
while($this->a !== $this->b){
  // Loop Contents
  sleep( $sometime );
}
```

Comment: Bad practice is to sleep in each loop when min sleep time is 1 second